# Adding Adsense to html

Tags: javascript, html, css, adsense

I can't seem to add adsense to my HTML
I currently have it in a div on the right side of my page (yellow box) but nothing is shown up and I have been very patient, been waiting for days now. Anyway here is my code.

HTML

```
<div id="AD2">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1234567890123456";
/* OAS ad */
google_ad_slot = "4238564948";
google_ad_width = 100%;
google_ad_height = 100%;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</div>
```

And my CSS which i use to organise it into place

```
#AD2 { background-color:#FF0; position:absolute; top:44%; right:1%; height:50%; width:10%; z-index:1;}
```

[Page Here](http://officialacescottie.co.uk/Home/Home.html)

Comment: Have you run through Google's troubleshooter? Might help diagnose the issue... https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/2473099

Comment: thanks i am trying this now.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines are incorrect:

```
google_ad_width = 100%;
google_ad_height = 100%;
```

These values must be set to actual numbers of pixels, not percentages. (As written, they are causing a syntax error because the `%` is being interpreted as the modulo operator, but is missing its right hand argument.)

Comment: OK i have edited the code to show to code given by Google. i have a notification saying i need to implement the code on my site. dose that mean any page or all pages or just the page it points to >
e.g. oas.co.uk/Home/Home.html is where i have put the code but oas.co.uk is where i told google my site is.
(url shortened for easy use)